# Sent RSA Key Through Autobahn

Tags: python, encryption, autobahn

I'm new in python and websocket programmer.

I want to sent data that was encrypted with RSA key (in Python) through websocket to server in cloud (using nodeJs). For decrypt that data I need that key, right? 
How I can sent RSA to server and use that key to decrypt?

Thankyou

Comment: You wouldn't generally send the private (decryption) key anywhere. Instead, you can embed the public (encryption) key in the client. So the key pair should be generated on the server.

Comment: What do you mean "embed the public key in the client"? Can you give me example?

Comment: I mean you should generate the key pair, encode the public key in some way and put it into the client source code. Then you can load it the client and encrypt something for the server.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided information on how you are encrypting your data. But you should never send the private keys over the network. Never. Doing that is as secure as locking your house but leave the key in the keyhole. If you've done it even once, throw the key away and generate a new one.

The strength of RSA comes from the fact that anyone holding the public key can encrypt data, but only the one holding the private keys can decrypt. Think of it as an old video store's return box: any costumer can put the videos in it through the hole, but only the store staff can take the videos from it.

What you want to do is:

1. Generate the keys on the server
2. Client call the server and grab the **public** key
3. Client encrypt data using the retrieved **public** key
4. Client send encrypted data to server.
5. Server decrypt it using the **private** key

Comment: I'd combine 1&2 by adding the public key into the code of the client so that the client doesn't have to additionally request the public key.